# Issues with PHP form submit with Google Maps Geocoded Lat Long

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, google-maps

I have a html form of mine which includes the following code.

```
<input type="text" style="opacity:0;" id="latlong" name="latlong" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit1" onClick="return validate();" value="Submit"/>
```

The Javascript's validate function looks like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
    if($("#near_buil_id").val()==''){
        var address = "\""+$("#nearest_building").val()+","+$("#flat").val()+","+$("#near_road").val()+","+$("#landmark").val()+","+$("#street").val()+","+$("#region").val()+","+$("#city").val()+","+$("#state").val()+"\"";
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            $("#latlong").val("POINT("+results[0].geometry.location.k+" "+results[0].geometry.location.A+")");
            //console.log($("#latlong").val());
            return true;
          }
          else{
            console.log(status);
            console.log(results);
            return false;
          }
          });
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

My issue is that when I submit this form, and try to take the value of `$_POST['latlong']`, a null value is obtained. 
Also, when I put `return false` at the end of the function and `console.log` the value that I am appending in `$("#latlong")`, I get the expected value.

Can anyone help me in resolving the issue?? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($_POST)` in your PHP script? I would like to see what data your server is receiving.

Comment: Problem is that `geocode()` is asynchronous function so you don't know when it will finish. You have to submit your data after latlng is set in `if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {` using something like `referenceToYourForm.submit();`. Those `return false` or `return true` won't help you.

Comment: Yes I have seen it before posting the question: 
It shows this for latlong:
`[latlong] => `

Answer (score 0):

In your `submit` button html you should move your code for `onclick` to `onsubmit`. `onsubmit` is run before the form is submitted whereas `onclick` is not, so in essence you are 'submitting' the form, with a null value in the `latlong` input, before your javascript code puts a value in the `latlong` input.

Note `onsubmit` should be a form attribute.

Comment: Its not working for me. My form tag looks like this: 
`<form name="frm" onsubmit="return validate();" method="post" id="register-form" action="index.php?rel=interaction_report_action">`
Submit field looks like this: 
`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>`

But it is not working for me..

Comment: Are you still getting the null value for `latlong`?

Comment: Yes I am getting the same result.